# Is it possible to show which virtual environment you are in when using git bash?

Tags: git-bash, virtual-environment

If I enter a pipenv virtual environment in command prompt, it will show which virtual environment I am in on the left side inside parentheses. Is there any way to have this same effect while using git bash?

Thank you!

Enter Virtual Environment: pipenv shell

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are trying to ask; but yes, it is reasonably common to have the Bash prompt configured to display the currently active virtual environment. Please search before asking; important keywords include `PS1` and `prompt_command` (either / or; I would vaguely recommend the former).